# Tag [boundaryvalueanalysis] was created instead of [boundary-value-analysis]

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag [boundaryvalueanalysis] was created instead of [boundary-value-analysis]

The first one is hard to read, and is not in written in common style here (with dash)

The question it was used in [Boundary Value Testing - Difference between three point and two point values [ISTQB - Adanced Test Analyst]](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26441/boundary-value-testing-difference-between-three-point-and-two-point-values-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only one question using the "boundaryvalueanalysis" tag, I renamed it to "boundary-value-analysis".